# Possible to turn callback calls into IEnumerable

Tags: c#, callback, enumerable

I'm writing a wrapper around a 3rd party library, and it has a method to scan the data it manages. The method takes a callback method that it calls for each item in the data that it finds.

e.g. The method is essentially: `void Scan(Action<object> callback);`

I want to wrap it and expose a method like `IEnumerable<object> Scan();`

Is this possible without resorting to a separate thread to do the actual scan and a buffer?

Comment: Could you outline the exact flow on your 3rd party library - it sounds like it is already spawning to multiple threads. Also keep in mind that you may have a Multicast delegates. Also how are you determining that the scan is finished?

Comment: To be honest, I can't see the value in doing this. If you want to do `foreach (object obj in scannable.Scan()) { /* do something with obj */ }`, is that really any better than `scannable.Scan(obj => { /* do something with obj */ });`?

Comment: @weismat: no, its not spawning threads, it basically iterates against it's data store internally, and calls the callback for each record.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Yes, that is doable, but I'm writing a wrapper for other people to use, so want it to be as obvious as possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this quite simply with Reactive:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var x in CallBackToEnumerable<int>(Scan))
            Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> CallBackToEnumerable<T>(Action<Action<T>> functionReceivingCallback)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {
            // Schedule this onto another thread, otherwise it will block:
            Scheduler.Later.Schedule(() =>
            {
                functionReceivingCallback(o.OnNext);
                o.OnCompleted();
            });

            return () => { };
        }).ToEnumerable();
    }

    public static void Scan(Action<int> act)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            // Delay to prove this is working asynchronously.
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            act(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that this doesn't take care of things like cancellation, since the callback method doesn't really allow it. A proper solution would require work on the part of the external library.

Comment: Hmmm, that will work nicely. I hoped to avoid have to use a separate thread, but it doesn't seem possible using only one thread. This seems the simplest way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's actually possible to get it into an Enumerable using only one thread. The closest I could get was an Observable, but in that case it's just a callback by another name :)

Answer (score 4):

You should investigate the [Rx project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) — this allows an event source to be consumed as an `IEnumerable`.

I'm not sure if it allows vanilla callbacks to be presented as such (it's aimed at .NET events) but it would be worth a look as it should be possible to present a regular callback as an `IObservable`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blocking enumerator (the Scan method needs to run in a separate thread)

```
    public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<object>
    {
        private readonly Queue<object> _queue = new Queue<object>();
        private ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public void Callback(object value)
        {
            lock (_queue)
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(value);
                _event.Set();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            _event.WaitOne();
            lock (_queue)
            {
                Current = _queue.Dequeue();
                if (_queue.Count == 0)
                    _event.Reset();
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _queue.Clear();
        }

        public object Current { get; private set; }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enumerator = new MyEnumerator();
        Scan(enumerator.Callback);

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
        }
    }
```

You could wrap it in a simple `IEnumerable<Object>`, but I would not recommend it. `IEnumerable` lists implies that you can run multiple enumerators on the same list, which you can't in this case.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
IEnumerable<Object> Scan()
{
    List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();

    Action<Object> action = (obj) => { objList.Add(obj); };

    Scan(action);

    return objList;
}
```

Comment: The `Scan(action)` might add items while the returned `IEnumerable` would be iterated resulting in an exception since the callback will execute async.

Comment: Yea, that works, but the potential number of callbacks can be in the millions, so I'd rather not buffer the whole lot up before iterating over it.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword -- which will allow you to have a method that looks like an `IEnumerable` but which actually does processing for each return value.

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP wants to know how to hook such a method up to an `Action<object>` callback.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean -- much more difficult question!

Comment: Yeah, my initial thought was a one-line method `Scan(x => { yield return x; });`, but unfortunately yield doesn't work like that.